# Set Value to ID Table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to show my id table like list of code(ex.L001) not just number (1) like this

[image]

This is my table and everything work good

[image]

can anyone help me please

Comment: No code - no help!

Comment: "No code" ==> Create a [mcve] of what you tried

Comment: no i have my table and everything work good just wont to make codification of my id

Comment: I can include the images in the body of the question by editing it but without showing the relevant code (As text - no screenshots of code please)  you will probably won't get help because nobody knows what your code looks like

Comment: It is not clear, please be more specific, whether you want to do with sql or with php?

Comment: what code i must show it s just  crud table this is my index.blade.php

Comment: hi @Rox i want to do it with php just show in my index change the id to specifique code like P001 not 1

Comment: *not ideal* but you can use laravel's mutator to set the value for id.

Comment: ok @usrNotFound i will try to do that

Comment: @haffisasma can you give me your query you are using to get data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by concat method of sql as

```
$data=DB::Select(DB::raw('SELECT concat("POO",id) as concated_id,other_column_names from table_name'));
```

Hope it helps.